# separation theorem and convex cone

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have just a small question in a proof in my functional analysis script. I have a set $A\subset L^p$, where the latter is the usual $L^p$ over a space with finite measure $\mu$. The set $A$ is also convex cone and closed in the weak topology. Furthermore we have $A\cap L^p_+=\{0\}$, i.e. the only non negative function in $A$ is the zero function. Let $g\in L^p_+\backslash \{0\}$. By the Hahn Banach separation theorem there is a $f\in L^q$

$$E[gf]\ge \beta > \alpha \ge E[f h]$$

for every $h\in A$. Where $\alpha = \sup_{h\in A}E[fh]$. Now they claim, by the cone property, that we can choose $\alpha =0 $. Of course, since $0\in A$, we know $\alpha \ge 0$, but why can I choose $\alpha$ identical zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $E$ is a notation for linear functional and $p,q$ are Holder conjugate exponentes, so I am gonna work with this. For each $h\in A$, we have by the cone property that $$\tag{1}\lambda h\in A,\ \forall\ \lambda\geq 0$$

Suppose that $\alpha> 0$ and choose $h\in A$ such that $E[fh]>0$. By $(1)$, we have that $\lambda h\in A$ for all $\lambda\geq 0$. This implies that $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} E[f(\lambda h)]=\infty$, which is an absurd, because $\alpha<\beta$.

Comment: In probability theory one often writes $E[f]$ for the integral $\int f$ due to its interpretation as Expectation.

Comment: Thank you Tomas for your answer. As Martin pointed out, $E[]$ denotes the expectation, so it is a linear functional. There is one small thing, which is not completely clear to me: In my script the say: W.l.o.g we can assume $\alpha=0$. But your argument actually shows, that $\alpha$ must be zero. It can't be positive. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes @hulik, I have proved that $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Do you see any error in my proof @hulik, I think it is correct.

Comment: No it seems correct. I was just confused about the statement in my script (W.l.o.g), when actually $\alpha$ has to be zero.

Comment: @Tomás Sorry for bothering you again after a while. Just one small question: Why do you now that $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}E[f(\lambda h)]=\infty$. of course, if I can put the limit inside this is clear.

Comment: Dear @hulik, $E$ being a linear functional, it satisfies the property $E[f(\lambda h)]=\lambda E[fh]$.